# Return Rows of Table as Nested Lists with Dictionaries as each Column

Tags: c#

I'm trying to store the rows into a list of a list of a list of dictionaries.  Basically in other words a list of Rows.  And Each row I am representing as a list of Key/value pairs (column/value)

```
public List<List<Dictionary<int, string>>> RowsIn(string databaseName, string tableName)
{
    const string localConnectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    CurrentConnection = new SqlConnection(localConnectionString);

    var rows = new List<List<Dictionary<int, string>>> { new List<Dictionary<int, string>>()};

    using (CurrentConnection)
    {
        CurrentConnection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader;
            using (var cmd2 = new SqlCommand("If Exists (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + tableName + "') SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = N'" + databaseName + "'", CurrentConnection))
            {
                using (reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (!reader.HasRows) return rows;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            rows.Add(
                                new List<Dictionary<int, string>>
                                {
                                    new Dictionary<int, int> {{i, reader.GetValue(i)}}
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    return new List<List<Dictionary<int, string>>>; // none found just return an empty list of rows
}
```

I don't know if I"m just going the hard way about this but I can't get this to work syntactically.  It's complaining about these 2 lines of code:

`new Dictionary<int, int> {{i, reader.GetValue(i)}}` - Error "Argument Type object is not assignable to parameter type in"

and

```
return new List<List<Dictionary<int, string>>>;
```

Comment: There is a [`GetInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method by the way..

Answer (score 0):

`reader.GetValue(i)` doesn't return an `int` but an `object` I guess. Cast it with `(int)reader.GetValue(i)` or I believe there is something like `reader.GetIntValue(i)` (or create an extension).